# Is it some performance difference between dynamic and direct variable return in javascript?

Tags: javascript

So, lets imagine we have next functions structure:

1)

```
   const foo = (value) => {  // imperative code writing
     return value ? 1 : 0
   }
```

2)

```
   const bar = (value) => { // declarative code writing
    const boo = value ? 1 : 0

    return boo
   }
```

Can someone tell me is there is some performance, style or logic difference btw using such two styles of code writing in JavaScript? Or maybe one of them is really better for using?

Thanks!

Comment: `const boo` is redundant, that's all. It may or may not get optimised away by the engine. Neither is specifically "imperative" or "declarative".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That'll be optimized out in the engine you're running the JavaScript in.

Even if it wasn't the performance hit will be so incredibly small that it's not worth worrying about.

Comment: Okay, but what about code styling and comfortable way of debug in such cases? Is there is some difference, maybe some one is better from this side

Comment: Personally I use the shorthand if it's a simple return statement like that. If I'm operating in a large block of code and need to step into what the returned result will be, I'll quickly write it out as your `2)` and debug, then write it back. Personally having redundant variables like `boo` makes code more verbose than it has to be for me, so I avoid it.

Comment: No problem. In personal projects like this it doesnt really matter but you may end up being told by an employer to use one way or the other.